# Spring Tool Suite4 Update Failed, Error Showing

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

When i am going to update my STS it's showing the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core,1.8.1.v20191107-0507
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui,1.8.1.v20191119-1757
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.mpc,1.8.1.v20191119-1757
```

What Should i do to update ? Does updating STS really necessary?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is usually caused by wrong or stale cache data for the update mechanism. There is a two step process that you can try to solve this:

- go to the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites`, select the update sites, and hit `Reload`. Sometimes this helps, but not always.
- if the first step doesn't solve the issue, I would suggest to go to the same preference page, select all update sites, and export them into a file (using the `Export` button). Then delete all of them and restart your IDE. Then import them back from the XML file using the `Import` button on that preference page.

That usually solves the issue. Whether you should update your IDE install? I would recommend to always update to the latest STS and Eclipse version, but in the end it is your choice.