# What are the correct update sites for Spring Tools Suite 4.18.1 Release?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tools-4

It seems I'm not the only one experiencing STS update problems:

Spring Tool Suite 4
Version: 4.18.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202305021758

Updates are impossible given the original update sites:

| Item | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Latest Eclipse Release | https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest |
| Linux Tools Docker Tooling | https://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/update-docker |
| Spring Tool Suite 4 | https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/latest |
| Spring Tools 4 Language Servers for Eclipse | https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4-language-server-integrations |

!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2023-12-16 10:40:40.616
!MESSAGE From: Eclipse Platform 4.27.0.v20230302-0300 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.27.0.v20230302-0300)
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2023-12-16 10:40:40.616
!MESSAGE To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.compare [3.8.500.v20220812-1406,3.8.500.v20220812-1406]
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2023-12-16 10:40:40.616
!MESSAGE Cannot satisfy dependency:
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2023-12-16 10:40:40.616
!MESSAGE From: Spring Tool Suite 4 4.18.1.202305021758 (org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.18.1.202305021758)
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2023-12-16 10:40:40.616
!MESSAGE To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.27.0.v20230302-0300,4.27.0.v20230302-0300]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE **An error occurred while collecting items to be installed**
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE **No repository found** containing: osgi.bundle,bcpg,1.76.0
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE **No repository found** containing: osgi.bundle,bcprov,1.76.0
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE **No repository found** containing: osgi.bundle,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations,2.15.2
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE **No repository found** containing: osgi.bundle,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core,2.15.2
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2023-12-16 10:50:25.802
!MESSAGE **No repository found** containing: osgi.bundle,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind,2.15.2

...error log goes on for miles

Comment: For that build ID, which presumably is not the latest but 7 months old, you should instead try using https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-03.

Comment: I guess I did not understand the update process. I had figured out that 2023-03 update site based on the STS release notes, but I am trying to update, and using that URL for the update site, STS, logically, found no updates.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is nothing wrong with the update sites.  I just did not understand the update process.

I had run across some comments about issues with 'cache'.

The solution was simply to "Reload" the update sites.

See Martin Lippert's answer and first solution here:

[Spring Tool Suite4 Update Failed, Error Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019461/spring-tool-suite4-update-failed-error-showing)